# What is a modern SSRS development environment in 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, postgresql-10, ssrs-2016

I'm having a difficult time attempting to set up SSRS with PostgreSQL 10.  No matter what I've tried I always end up with "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

I have read that everything must match, 32 bit vs 64 bit.  However modern Visual Studio only comes in 32, but a modern SQL server (necessary for the report server) only comes in 64.  I'm not sure what Report builder 3 is, but it doesn't work either.  I've tried ODBC DSN's for 32 and 64,  separate specific names and same name for both types, doesn't seem to make any difference.

Visual studio 2017 with SSDT will preview the report in the builder, but error when running in the browser (architecture mismatch error).  The Report builder will also not run the report at all, even though it claims the connection to the database is successful.

So after finding out of date answers from the past decade, maybe it's best to put it as the title does.  If you were to set up the most modern SSRS setup with postgreSQL, what versions of what tools would you use to develop / test / deploy reports?

Comment: Do you have the 64 bit driver installed on the SSRS server? _Some_ vendors drivers don't allow you to 64 and 32 bit at the same time. Most vendors drivers have different "driver names" between 32 and 64 bit. A typical install would be: install both 32 and 64 bit drivers on the development machine and the server machine. Can you ensure both are installed, then use both versions of ODBCAD32.EXE (the 32 and 64 bit versions), go to the driver tab and confirm what the driver names are?

Comment: This https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/ appears to indicate that the driver name may be the same between 32 nd 64 bit versions. In the examples on the page, the driver name is for example, `{PostgreSQL}`, `{PostgreSQL UNICODE}`, `{PostgreSQL ANSI}`

Comment: I've been creating system DSNs in the ODBC Administrators (32 and 64 bit versions), then I'm referencing the dsns for the connection string.  The system DSNs look like they are referencing the appropriate drivers, the 64 bit is looking at "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)" and the 32 bit version "PostgreSQL Unicode". Most of the various parts of the process that allow you to "Test Connection" do repport a successful connection, but then moving forward and actually running the report there are issues as I mention above.

Comment: That should work (but obviously it doesn't!). I assume the SSRS Server and the development tools are on the same host? You could try using a DSNless connection string and that way you would be explicitly referencing the 64 bit driver (rather than a DSN that refers to it)

Comment: Here's a guide I found - I'm sure you've already done all this but it wouldn't hurt to go through it wit ha fine tooth comb. http://blog.i-m-code.com/2013/06/03/connect-ssrs-to-postgresql-database/

Comment: The bottom of this article shows an example of a DSNless connection string. It's obviously showing a 32 bit connection as the driver name doesn't contain x64  https://support.quadrahosting.com/kb-article-23-0,3,15.html

Comment: ... and this one shows how to define a DSNless connection in SSRS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/odbc-connection-type-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue with connecting to Redshift. Report Builder requires a 32-bit connection while the Report Server requires a 64-bit connection. The way we solved this was to create a 32-bit DSN on the computers where reports are being developed. We created a 64-bit DSN with the same name on the report server.

During report development, it uses the 32-bit connection. When you deploy, it recognizes that DSN name and uses the 64-bit version on the server.

You can test the data sources on both sides to make sure the drivers are installed correctly. As long as they both work independently and have the same name, the deployment shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes, I just did the same thing this week.